# How to calculate (in R) the range in the difference of ranges to check if 0 is within this range?

Tags: r, range, confidence-interval

I am studying the relationship of one Variable `Y` with two possible explanatory variables `X1` and `X2`. All my variables are continuous. Furthermore, `Y` has a non-normal distribution, so I decided to evaluate separately the relationship of `X1` and `X2` with `Y` using the correlation coefficient of Spearman. I get a correlation coefficient called `rho` with a Confidence Interval `C.I` (= a range) for either Y~X1 (`rho1`) and Y~X2 (`rho2`). I want to calculate the range of possible differences between `rho1` and `rho2`, and check if 0 is within this range.

As an example:

```
rho1 <- range(0.90,0.92)
rho2 <- range(0.91,0.93)

Range

0.00  0.03     # The difference between `rho1` and `rho2` is between 0 and
```

Another example:

```
rho1 <- range(0.85,0.88)
rho2 <- range(0.89,0.91)

Range

0.01  0.06
```

I want to calculate the range of possible differences between `rho1` and `rho2` to check, as I said, if 0 is within this range and then say that the strength of the relationship of `rho1` and `rho2` with `Y` is likely the shame. In this example, the range of possible differences is:

Do you know how to calculate the mentioned range?

Comment: Do you want to calculate difference between one another or combined? So something like this `range(abs(outer(rho1, rho2, \`-\`)))` or `temp <- c(rho1, rho2);range(abs(outer(temp, temp, \`-\`)))` ?

Comment: In your first example why the output is `0.00`? Which 2 elements have difference as 0 ?

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah. I think none of those options are correct. I tried both and I didn't get what I expected. The second one (`temp <- c(rho1, rho2);range(abs(outer(temp, temp, `-`)))`) is close, however, when I run it with the second example I don't get the range I would expect (`0.01  0.06`)

Comment: In the first example, `rho1` could be `0.915` (this value is within the range of `rho1`) and `rho2` too, so 0 is one of the possible differences between the two ranges. Do you understand?

Comment: Please check the output of `range(0.90,0.92)` it is just 2 numbers is that what you mean to say here? I think what you needed was `seq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I had misunderstood the question earlier. We need to check if any value in a vector is between other value in the another vector.

```
get_difference_values <- function(x, y) {
  if(any(dplyr::between(x, min(y), max(y))))
    c(0, max(max(x) - min(y), max(y) - min(x)))
  else
    range(abs(outer(x, y, `-`)))
}

rho1 <- range(0.90,0.92)
rho2 <- range(0.91,0.93)
get_difference_values(rho1, rho2)
#[1] 0.00 0.03

rho1 <- range(0.85,0.88)
rho2 <- range(0.89,0.91)
get_difference_values(rho1, rho2)  
#[1] 0.01 0.06
```

---

**Old answer**

In the reproducible example I think what you need is `seq` and not `range`.

We can use `outer` to get difference between every element of `rho1`, `rho2`, get their absolute value and get the `range`.

```
rho1 <- seq(0.90,0.92, 0.01)
rho2 <- seq(0.91,0.93, 0.01)
range(abs(outer(rho1, rho2, `-`)))
#[1] 0.00 0.03


rho1 <- seq(0.85,0.88, 0.01)
rho2 <- seq(0.89,0.91, 0.01)

range(abs(outer(rho1, rho2, `-`)))
#[1] 0.01 0.06
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Shah for your time. This option works with the second example but not with the first one. I need a unique code that works in both situations.

Comment: My problem is that R gives me a confidence interval for the `rho` statistic. R doesn't give me a sequence of values, it just gives a range within which `rho` can take any value. So I don't know how to manage the `seq` argument here...

Comment: You could use `do.call(seq, c(as.list(rho1), by = 0.01))` to create the sequence for both the numbers and then use it in `outer` as described.

Comment: @Dekike I think I had misunderstood the question earlier, I have updated the answer. Although the older answer isn't completely accurate but I'll keep it since it can still be used to get answer.